# Getting all elements null on converting of JSON to OBJECT

Tags: android, json, android-studio, kotlin, jsonparser

> The issue I'm getting:
>
> **All elements are null**
>
> way I'm using

```
>THis jsonFileString is basically the json file response
val jsonFileString="[{"time": "0min_2sec","sentence": "The first words I spoke in the original phonograph."},{"time": "0min_7sec", "sentence": "A little piece of practical poetry."},{"time": "0min_10sec","sentence": "Mary had a little lamb, its fleece was white as snow."},{"time": "0min_14sec","sentence": "And everywhere that Mary went, the lamb was sure to go."}]"

val gson = Gson()
val subtitlesList = gson.fromJson<ArrayList<SubtitlesList>>(
            jsonFileString,
            object : TypeToken<ArrayList<SubtitlesList>>() {}.type
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this and I tried this code:

```
    val gson = Gson()
    val list = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Array<City>::class.java)
    val cities : List<City> = Arrays.asList(*list)
```

This may help you!